# Access pure numbers alone

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with values which can either be numbers alone or a mix of numbers and letters as shown:

[image: Log Values]

I have an if statement in my macro. I want to run the statement, only when the value of the Activecell is a pure number and not a mix of numbers and letters. For instance, in the above case, I want the if statement to work only on the values such as 111156, 102963, 112224, etc and not on HE2790 etc. I want to loop to continue till the very end skipping those cells which have a hybrid entry. I have entries starting with various other combinations of letters also. Can someone suggest me a macro which can work according to my need?

The code I have tried is as follows

```
Do While ActiveCell.value <> ""
    If ActiveCell.value.IsNumeric() Then
        //code
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
```

I also tried IsNumber() instead of IsNumeric(), but in vain.

It will be nice if someone can help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value)`

This runs fine for me:

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        Debug.Print "numeric"
    Else
        Debug.Print "not"
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Usage of IsNumeric in incorrect. See below to fix it.

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) Then
      'Code
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
```